# How to implement HTTP Basic Auth in Play Framework 1.2?

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x, basic-authentication

[I found this post](http://digitalsanctum.com/2012/06/07/basic-authentication-in-the-play-framework-using-custom-action-annotation/), but it is aimed at Play 2.0.

Has anyone done this for Play 1 (I'm using 1.2.4-mbknor-3)?

Answer (score 6):

The `Http.Request` object has `user` and `password` properties populated from the Authorization header.  You could do something like this:

```
public class Application extends Controller {   
  private static final String WWW_AUTHENTICATE = "WWW-Authenticate";
  private static final String REALM = "Basic realm=\"Your Realm Here\"";

  @Before
  static void authenticate() {
    if (!("username".equals(request.user) && "password".equals(request.password))) {
      response.setHeader(WWW_AUTHENTICATE, REALM);
      error(401, "Unauthorized");
    }
  }

  public static void index() {
    renderText("Welcome!");
  }
}
```